# extracting HTML5 and javascript library APIs from web pages inside android application

Tags: javascript, html, static-code-analysis, web-content

I am a researcher and and I have a project on Android web based mobile application analysis. For analyzing my data set which includes so many android apk files, I wanna to extract HTML or HTML5 APIs which has been used in application web pages. I can extract used urls in the application, but I do not know how can I load or find which web and javascript APIs will be load in the application web content at run time. In the application, we may have javascript libraries, Jquery and etc which are important too.

Is there any mechanism or tool which I load the url content in that and analyse the web content? Another thing is that. some of the application web pages maybe need user user pass or based on different users load different web content.

Briefly, How can I find which web APIs have been used in the application?

Answer (score 0):

I need to crawl my urls with a Scrapy in python such as scrapy.

there is a good scrapy in python [here](https://scrapy.org/).